# How to make the max width inherent OR initial (whichever comes first) in css?

Tags: html, css, image, styles, width

I'm trying to have an image auto resize until it fills a div or reaches its initial size. I want it to grow as the div grows but stop when its initial size is reached. I also want it to retain its original aspect ratio the entire time. Is this possible only using css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add some additional detail. If this is as straightforward as you describe, just don't set a width in CSS, and apply a max-width;

```
img{
   max-width:100%
}
```

and it won't exceed it's natural width. See fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6hLz5em2/

Comment: I updated my fiddle, but the question is still vague. In this example, the div is full width, and has an image inside of it that is fluid until it's natural size, and the parent stretches until it reaches natural width. https://jsfiddle.net/6hLz5em2/7/ If there's something we're missing here, let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for.

```
img{
  width:100vh;
  height:100vh;
}
```